# Sendgrid node js receive email

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to receive email from contact us form to company website and I want to show the user's email in "from" part rather than the company's own email. Otherwise the sendgird won't work. Here is my code:

```
var msg = {
from: company_email, // I want here to be the user's email instead of company's
to: company_email,
subject: subject,
text: "some random message"  }


sgMail.send(msg, (error, response) => {
if(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
else{
    console.log(response);
}})
```

Comment: If you're keeping a session of the user, you could take user's email from it. Another option would be to provide an email address field on the form and send it to that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I am working with third party API 'sendgrid' and it won't let me use any other email in the "from" other than the verified email. I want to send email from user's email to company's email without having the user log in or anything